# Italic greek letters, upright operators and working partial sign with unicode-math and TeX Gyre Pagella

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

I need upright math operators such as `\sin`, `\tan` etc., italic uppercase greek letters and a working `\partial` operator. With the code below I was able to get two out of three, but I was told that it's not the recommended way of achieving what I need (see comments). And I still need a `\partial` sign.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=.9]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{TeX Gyre Pagella Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{TeX Gyre Pagella Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {TeX Gyre Pagella Italic}

\begin{document}

$x\partial x$

\end{document}
```

How can I get all three things working?

Comment: Why do you need those ranges? Aren't they provided by default with TeX Gyre Pagella Math? I mean, those are useful if you want to change the fonts, and you clearly don't.

Comment: I had a problem which I was able to solve that way, but I don't remember what it exactly was. I check my document without, maybe I don't need them anymore.

Comment: @Manuel: I found the problem again. Without these lines, `\sin`, `\tan` etc. are printed in italic, and I found this solution on tex.sx. So, do you know why this does not work? Otherwise I have to ask a new question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry for not telling the whole story, but as an excuse: it's late here. The problem is: I need the option `math-style=ISO` to get italic greek characters but that changes `\sin` etc., which I was able to reconstruct as seen above. But that makes me losing my `\partial`. Is there a way to achieve all: italic greek letters, upright operators and a working partial sign?

Comment: @Chris: Wherever you found this solution, I’m certain it is wrong, and the missing partial is not the only issue you will face with this “fix”.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Thanks for the clarification. But then, how can I achieve all together: italic greek characters, upright operators and a working partial sign? I tried to find it in the unicode-math manual but there seems no predefined style that does this.

Comment: I think you need to update the question to reflect this, someone might have a proper answer.

Comment: BTW, here I get upright `\sin` even after removing all the `range` invocations.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: That's true, workd with my minimal example as well but not with the real document. I updated the question but it makes no sense anymore. I construct a new minimal example and maybe I find the error myself.

Comment: Adding `\setmathfont[range=\partial]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}` after the other range declarations resurrects the partial derivative symbol. But I agree with @KhaledHosny it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: @egreg: I agree with both of you. I found the reason now. Loading amsmath after unicode-math gives the italic operators, loading it before is safe. I need it to get the pmatrix-environment. So, a fourth package is involved. Thanks for all your help, Manuel, Khaled Hosny and egreg. I'll try to change the question again to reflect the problem and maybe my solution if the solution is OK.

Comment: `amsmath` should be loaded ***before*** `unicode-math`; see the manual just after “Getting started”.

Comment: @egreg: Now that I know it I found it in the manual as well. Thanks again for all your help. I'll post an answer for those that observe similar problems and stumble over my question.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I was able to find the reason with the great help of the comments to my question. For those observing similar problems, I post an answer here.

1. The missing `\partial` comes from reassigning unicode ranges to different fonts. Don't do it unless you know what the side effects are. I didn't and therefore another problem was hidden by this wrong solution.
2. The option `math-style=ISO` did not break my math operators. Loading `amsmath` after `unicode-math` was the problem (It's stated in the unicode-math manual that amsmath must be loaded before but I was searching for the error somewhere else, thinking that the italic operators were intentionaly set by unicode-math).

So, loading amsmath before unicode-math and removing the range reassignments in the question's code solves everything.

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the correct code.